# Round Off Number in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Can any one tell me how to round of the number in sencha touch with Ext.util.Formate or Ext.Number ?

Ex: 1523.6592(Before Round Off),
    1523.63(Should be After Round Off)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Ext.util.Format.number(1523.6592, '0.00');
```

Comment: Nope we didn't get anything